# Remove duplicate emails from to , cc and bcc to send grid

Tags: c#, .net

I have a lambda expression to remove duplicate emails from to cc and bcc.
lstCCEmailAddress.Remove(lstCCEmailAddress.Where(t => t.Email.Contains(email.Email, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).FirstOrDefault());

but the thing is I want to remove all the duplicate emails just not FirstOrDefault.
which one should I replace FirstOrDefault with

How can I re-write the above query.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if it's List<string> type, just do distinct, if its List<somekindofClass> type, you need to group by email first and select first group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove duplicates for all those fields (TO,CC,BCC),

- first you need to run distinct on "To"
- second run distinct on "cc" then remove any emails which does exists from "to".
- third run distinct on "bcc" and remove any records which does exists from "to" and "cc" fields

  ```
     [Fact] 
        public void TestUniqeEmails()
        {
            var listToEmail = new List<string> { "a@a.com", "b.com", "b.com" };
            var listCCToEmail = new List<string> { "a@a.com", "b.com", "c.com" };
            var listBCCToEmail = new List<string> { "a@a.com", "b.com", "c.com", "d.com" };

            var uniqueToEmail = listToEmail.Distinct();

            var uniqueCCEmail = listCCToEmail
                    .Where(e => !uniqueToEmail.Any(e.Contains))
                    .Distinct();

            var uniqueBCCEmail = listBCCToEmail
                 .Where(e => !listToEmail.Any(e.Contains))
                  .Where(e => !uniqueCCEmail.Any(e.Contains))
                  .Distinct();

            Assert.Equal(2, uniqueToEmail.ToList().Count);
            Assert.Single(uniqueCCEmail.ToList());
            Assert.Single(uniqueBCCEmail.ToList());
        }
  ```

Comment: Thank you all for your reply. I have to remove the duplicate emails . My code worked , in foreach loop I had mistakenly added torecipeints instead of ccrecipients. when I fixed it I was able to send email to send grid successfully.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **.Distinct()** function Of Linq.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        List<string> mail = new List<string>() { "test@gmail", "blub@gmail", "test@gmail" };

        var x = mail.Distinct();

        foreach (var item in x)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Result:
test@gmail
blub@gmail

For more information:

https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct?view=net-5.0

Answer (score 0):

You can group by and select group

```
var DistinctItems = lstCCEmailAddress.GroupBy(x => x. Email).Select(y => y.First());
```